# accessing Node* from a class

Tags: c++

I have a class List that is made up of a Node* list and the private field also contains a Node struct:
          struct Node {
              int value;
              Node *next;
           };

I am developing a friend function with parameters (const List& a, const List&b)

when I am developing code because the Lists are constant I created temp variables:

```
              Node* q=a.list;
              Node* r=b.list;
```

but the compiler says Node was not declared in this scope
then `q` was not declared in the scope either (same thing for r) Not understanding how this is happening?

Comment: Can we get the source? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to post more code to get a good answer.
As it stands, the error means compiler isn't seeing the "Node" type in the scope available at that line.
Is Node a subtype? if so, try List::Node?

btw, if passing const List& a, you would need your Node* 's to be const too.

(by more code, I mean the relevant struct/class declaration, and perhaps a little file structure info, more of the calling code wont help much)